# Error on upgrading from Pimcore 10.5 to 10.6 . Preparing for Pimcore v11

Tags: php, pimcore, pimcore-datahub

On upgrading from 10.5 to 10.6,

Got the Error pointing to line 99 in `C:\wamp64\www\pomodoro\pomodoro\vendor\pimcore\pimcore\lib\Model\Dao\AbstractDao.php`

Updated comspose.json with `"pimcore/pimcore": "10.6",` in the require block.

Executed `composer update -W`

Output: `Exit Code 1`

Attempted
`C:\wamp64\bin\php\php8.0.26\php.exe --php-ini=C:\wamp64\bin\php\php8.0.26\php.ini bin/console --ansi assets:install --symlink --relative --ignore-maintenance-mode public`

Output:
`In AbstractDao.php line 99: Warning: Undefined array key "columns`

Comment: Sounds like a problem with Pimcore itself, but not with Composer. What have you tried to resolve it?

Comment: I am also following responses to my query on [github/pimcore](https://github.com/pimcore/pimcore/discussions/16116#discussioncomment-7322559) Since I started from a fresh install of 10.5, I am unable to figure out a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1:

```
php bin\console doctrine:migrations:migrate
> yes
```

Step 2

```
C:\wamp64\bin\php\php8.0.26\php.exe --php-ini=C:\wamp64\bin\php\php8.0.26\php.ini bin/console --ansi assets:install --symlink --relative --ignore-maintenance-mode public
```

Success